# Invertibility of linear maps (Exercise 3D.4 of Axler's "Linear Algebra Done Right")

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm studying linear algebra on my own using Axler's book. This one exercise is driving me crazy.  So far, most of the exercises in the book have been quite easy, so I guess I'm just missing a point.

I just have a problem with one of the proof directions, where I have to show the following:

Suppose we have vector spaces $V$ and $W$, where $W$ is finite-dimentional (but not necessarily $V$), and let $T_1$ and $T_2$ be linear maps $V\rightarrow W$ with ${\rm null} T_1 = {\rm null} T_2$. Then there exists an invertible linear map $S: W\rightarrow W$ such that $T_1 = S T_2$.

I had the following strategy in mind: first show that ${\rm null} T_1 = {\rm null} T_2$ implies that
$\dim {\rm range }T_1 = \dim {\rm range }T_2$. Then this would imply that there is an isomorphism
between ${\rm range }T_1$ and ${\rm range }T_2$ . Then try to extend the domain of this map to all of $W$.
So far, I can only show that the dimensions of the ranges match if $V$ is finite-dimensional, but not
for $V$ infinite-dimensional. But even if I could show the first step in general, extending the domain to all of $W$
seems quite cumbersome.

I have spent at least 8 hours on this single exercise, I’m feeling stuck and my ideas seem to go in circles.

Can anybody please give me a hint how to proceed or point me to an alternative approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Call $K$ the kernel (aka null space) of $T_1$ and $T_2$. Both ranges $T_1V$ and $T_2V$ are isomorphic to $V/K$ by the first-isomorphism theorem (the rank-nullity theorem is just the dimensional version of this), so they are isomorphic to each other (in particular, they have the same dimension). Indeed, $T_1v\leftrightarrow T_2v$ is a well-defined one-to-one correspondence $T_1V\cong T_2V$ (which is an isomorphism of vector spaces). Check it's well-defined.

Both $T_1V$ and $T_2V$ are subspaces of $W$. We can give each a complement, so $W=W_1\oplus T_1V$ and $W=W_2\oplus T_2V$, say. We can construct an automorphism $S\in GL(W)$ by using the aforementioned isomorphism $T_1V\cong T_2V$ and picking an isomorphism $W_1\cong W_2$.

Comment: +1 This is amazing -the use of the first isomorphism theorem :).

Comment: That's an elegant proof, but it makes use of $V/K$ and other theorems, which are not yet introduced up to that point in the book. So, I guess I'm supposed to solve the exercise at this stage only using more basic arguments....

Comment: @mathieub As I said in the last bit of my first paragraph, we can show $T_1V\cong T_2V$ by showing $T_1v\leftrightarrow T_2v$ is well-defined (since $T_1u=T_1v$ and $T_2u=T_2v$ are both equivalent to $u-v\in K$). You don't actually have to reference the isomorphism theorem for this (since this is basically proving the isomorphism in this special case). It's a natural thing to do; you yourself thought of showing $T_1$ and $T_2$ have isomorphic ranges, and the ranges' elements all look like $T_1v$ and $T_2v$, so the natural thing is to check $T_1v\leftrightarrow T_2v$ makes sense.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for the comment!!